# How to calculate the time left untill some date

Tags: java, android, date

I want to find the time left till some day and time. 
I mean that if the target time is March 27th ( year 2017 ) at 10 oclock 
and today is March 10th 8 oclock so the time left is 17 days and 2 hours.

Is there some way using the date android API to calculate this time left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by calling this method:

```
public static Map<TimeUnit,Long> computeDiff(Date date1, Date date2) {
    long diffInMillies = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    List<TimeUnit> units = new ArrayList<TimeUnit>(EnumSet.allOf(TimeUnit.class));
    Collections.reverse(units);
    Map<TimeUnit,Long> result = new LinkedHashMap<TimeUnit,Long>();
    long milliesRest = diffInMillies;
    for ( TimeUnit unit : units ) {
        long diff = unit.convert(milliesRest,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        long diffInMilliesForUnit = unit.toMillis(diff);
        milliesRest = milliesRest - diffInMilliesForUnit;
        result.put(unit,diff);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It give you a map of timeUnit and their value like:

```
Map:{DAYS=1, HOURS=3, MINUTES=46, SECONDS=40, MILLISECONDS=0, MICROSECONDS=0, NANOSECONDS=0},
```

Then you can convert it to anything you want.

Comment: How do we read Map<TimeUnit,Long> ?

Comment: here its result.get(TimeUnit.DAYS) and etc

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 long futureTimeMillis;
 long currentTimeMillis
 DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(futureTimeMillis, currentTimeMillis, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
```